# haskell function / pattern operator

Tags: haskell

A friend of mine showed me the following code:

```
calculateAge :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
calculateAge (d2, m2, y2)
   | 11 > m2 = 2021 - y2
   | 11 == m2 && 10 >= d2 = 2021 - y2
   | otherwise = 2021 - y2 - 1
```

What does the | operator stand for? Is it just if the pattern are matching that the rest will get executed? Or is it like a Constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` is not an operator. It is a [*guard* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)). The expression after the `|` is a boolean expression. If it evaluates to `True`, then it will "fire" the expression that is associated with it.

This thus means that if the pattern matches, the guards will be evaluated top to bottom, and for the first guard that evaluates to `True`, it will fire the corresponding expression. `otherwise` is just an alias for `True`, so `otherwise` will always evaluate to `True`. This means that if no guard listed before the `otherwise` guard fires, the clause with `otherwise` will fire.